# Prompt loop when getting user to copy text in a textbox using prompt and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, prompt

I have written the following code to prompt the user with the content of a textbox to make it easy for them to copy the data. It's for non IT-savvy users who may not know how to copy text (we get them...)

```
    $('#saveBox').focusin(function(){
        var text = $('#saveBox').val();
        window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: press Ctrl+C and then Enter to close", text);
    });
```

However, this seems to create a loop, every time the user closes the box it pops up again.

Is there a way to only open the prompt when the user first clicks on the text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do that is using a boolean variable to do this action only the first time, like this example:

```
firstTime = true

$('#saveBox').focusin(function(){
    if(firstTime){
        var text = $('#saveBox').val();
        window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: press Ctrl+C and then Enter to close", text);
        firstTime = false;
    }
});
```

Without boolean:

```
$('#saveBox').one("focusin", function(){
    if(firstTime){
        var text = $('#saveBox').val();
        window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: press Ctrl+C and then Enter to close", text);
    }
});
```